# Environment variable is set but not accessible on server

Tags: java, environment-variables

I have a Java program which accesses some property files for it to work through a path which is set as an environment variable. I set the path using export command. The Java `jar` file which is the executable is placed under some different user, and hence I use the `sudo` option to run the `jar` file.

My problem is, when I set the environment variable on a test server, the program runs fine, however, when I make the same config settings on a production server, and try to run it, it shows that the path set for environment variable is null.

I know this has got something to do with the access or perhaps different server configs but as I am new to UNIX, I am not sure where I can start investigating.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

Environment variables *for a user* can be set in ~/.profile  however since you are running some commands as root this will not work unless you also change roots .profile file.

Another option is to change the file /etc/profile to add the paths and this should work for all users.

Answer (score 0):

Places to check for environment variables

```
/etc/environment
/etc/profile
~/.profile
~/.bashrc
```

If you export a variable as userA and then launch the jar using sudo, this variable won't be copied into userA's environment.

A quick workaround is to run the command as:

```
PATH=$PATH:/your/directory asdf.jar
```

That will set the PATH for just this invocation of your jar file.

You can also verify what that program's environment looks like by getting its pid and running `cat /proc/<pid>/environ`

This will show you all environment variables available to your program.